# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (32768, 1)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
y = train['class']
images_train, images_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, y, random_state=42, 
test_size=0.2, stratify = y)

y_train = pd.get_dummies(y_train)
y_test = pd.get_dummies(y_test)

base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

images_train = base_model.predict(images_train)
images_train.shape

images_test = base_model.predict(images_test)
images_test.shape

images_train = images_train.reshape(2321, 8*8*512)
images_test = images_test.reshape(581, 8*8*512)
max = images_train.max()
images_train = images_train/max
images_test = images_test/max

images_train.shape

model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(10, 8, 8, 512),filters=4,kernel_size= 
(3,3),padding="same",activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same",activation="relu"))

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint('weight.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
import tensorflow as tf
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images_train, y_train))
valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images_test, y_test))
model.fit(train_data, epochs=40, validation_data=valid_data, callbacks=[mcp_save], 
batch_size=10)
```

[ERROR:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O22E0.png)

I have created a dataset consisting of four different activities which are

1. blowing nose
2. falling down
3. chest pain
4. vomiting
   from three views left ,right and front , this sums up to 180 videos in total. Then I have extracted frames from each activity videos so I have total 2902 frames. I am trying to input these frames to CNN model . I am  getting the error as shown in the above as a learner I am not able to solve this error. Please help me to solve this error .

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to read that much out of your code, but your input shape is wrong for the network. You try to feed images_train into your VGG net. The VGG net needs as input a four-dimensional numpy array. This has the shape (batch_size, channels, width, height) or (batch_size, width, height, channels), depending on whether you selected the "channels_last" or the "channels_first" dataformat (I do not exactly know where to set this, but nevertheless one of them should work).

Your input to your network does not have this shape, this is why you get an error. Try to run np.shape(images_train), then you can see the shape of your input. If this is not four-dimensional, then your input is not correctly shaped for VGG net.